# React Native: how can i press on flatlist item and open specific screen for that item?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to press on a flat item and then open a new screen which has details from the item but how is the best way to do that?
should I make a modal and give it the details?
or should I make a new screen for every item?

```html
const renderRecipe = ({ item }) => {
    return (

      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.image }}>
        </Image>
        <Text style={{
          color: '#00aecc', fontSize: 18,
          marginTop: 15
        }}>{item.label}</Text>
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff', marginTop: 100, fontSize: 20 }}>Zutaten:</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: '#00aecc', fontSize: 18, marginTop: 15 }}>{item.id}</Text>
        </View>
      </View >
    )
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {isLoading && <View style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}><ActivityIndicator style={styles.loading} color='#00aecc' size="large" /></View>}
      <FlatList
        data={userRecipes}
        renderItem={renderRecipe}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}>
      </FlatList>
    </View >
  );
```

This is my item now how can I do what I want.

Comment: Are u using react navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain. You have two screens `Home` and `Details`.

Assume in your `Home` screen your `Flatlist`. So when you click to item on `Flatlist` you will navigate to `Details` screen with items details.That's it!

You can also do this with modal. But here it depends on requirement. There is not any perfect solution. Based on case scenario you do it.

In your case I will do followings.
First I will import TouchableOpactiy and useNavigation.

```
import {TouchableOpactiy} from 'react-native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

Then I will use it to my flatlist items.
```

`Home Screen`

```
 const Home = () => {
    
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    
    const renderRecipe = ({ item }) => {
         return (
          <TouchableOpactiy onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Details', {item} )}>
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.image }}>
             </Image>
             <Text style={{
               color: '#00aecc', fontSize: 18,
               marginTop: 15}}>{item.label}</Text>
            <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
              <Text style={{ color: '#fff', marginTop: 100, fontSize: 20 }}>Zutaten: 
              </Text>
              <Text style={{ color: '#00aecc', fontSize: 18, marginTop: 15 }}>{item.id} 
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View >
      </TouchableOpactiy>
        )
      }
    
    return (
     /*your flalist*/
     )
   }
```

`Details Screen`

```
const Details = ({ route, navigation ) => {
  const { item } = route.params;
 
  return (
    <Text>{item.label}</Text>
 )
}
```